# Load a form on click edit & save on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I searched through internet but i didn't got proper solution for this. I have attached two images. please have a look to it.

[image]

In this i am showing the details of the user. So on click `edit` i am showing the form in a pop up but i want to show in same place it self. Like

[image]

On save the changes will reflect in the previous image.

How can i achieve it by JS/Jquery/PHP etc. Any idea guys.

I have tried the code like this

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".reply").click(function(){
        if($("#someId").css("display") == "none"){
           $("#someId").show();
        } else {
           $("#someId").hide();
        }
     });
  });
```

But no i am changing the view only once.

Comment: How can i achieve it by JS/Jquery/PHP  <-- You should write some code for that.. Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Yes i tried show & hide methods but i no result. if i can get some sample to follow the procedure.

Comment: We need to see the code you have already

Comment: I'm curious why show-hide methods didn't work. Make two divs, one is for info and one is for form. Give hidden display style to form div first and when on clicking edit, make it display block or whatever you use and make info div display hidden.

Comment: 1) Need your current code. 2) You need to explain what's happening with your current code. PS: Try something like: `$("#edit").click(function(e){
  $("#edit_form").fadeIn("fast");
  e.preventDefault();
 });`

Comment: Any demo or sample is there to do it ?

Comment: What do you mean by "pop up but i want to show in same place it self"? Is the edit mode in a pop up window or it replace the location of the first image?

Comment: I am showing the form in a pop up now but i want to change as per the image.

Answer (score 0):

The easyiest way i think it's to send the data by jQuery.ajax tools.

```
jQuery('#your form id').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDeafult();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var data = {};
    jQuery(this).find(':enabled').each(function(obj, ind) {
        var $this = $(this);
        e.data[ $this.attr('name') ] = $this.val();
    })
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'this is your url',
        data: data
    }).success(function() {
        alert('sended');
        // document.location('куда-нибудь локайшен');
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.error('Error: ' + err);
    })
})
```

Comment: Before submit i need to change the view ...from details to form & vice  versa.. Any solution for that